# Is it possible to use TYPO3 as asset management for other TYPO3 installations (FAL)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, asset-management

Is it possible to use a a file_storage of a remote TYPO3 installation in a local installation?

I would like to override some configs in a local environment to use the productions file storage via https. That way snychronizing my local installation would become much faster and i would not need to rsync fileadmin for all projects (which would save some of my valuable ssd disk space)

Additionally i could simply use TYPO3 as asset manegement for different TYPO3 instances.

Has anybody every accomplished something like that?

It would be even better, if the solution is able to host the processed files too, i think using TYPO3 itself as asset management would be a perfect solution to centralize assets in a TYPO3 based website/system.

Comment: I don't think I get what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "asset management" and what is supposed to host what? Do you want a centralized typo3 installation that's hosting your fileadmin files and access them from other typo3 installations (whether they're live or production)?

Comment: Yes, i mean something like DAM.

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure how much time you want to spend into that, but have you tried looking at implementing your own driver? Take a look at: `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/Driver`

Comment: Thats plan b if it has not been solved already, thank you :)

Comment: I've not seen such a thing. Exposing the TYPO3 FAL via WebDav would be the best solution, since one could use the webdav driver to mount it then.

Comment: @PhilippWrann If you end up implementing your own driver, I would love if you put it on github or something, so I can contribute.

Comment: I was pointed out to https://github.com/dkd/typo3-ext-cmis-fal by a user in the typo3 slack chat. Don't know what CMIS though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use https://github.com/dkd/typo3-ext-cmis-service on the TYPO3 instance that shall expose its FAL, and use https://github.com/dkd/typo3-ext-cmis-fal to mount that exposed repository in the other TYPO3 instance.

I've not tested that :)